# Deriving microstrip stub equations

Tags: rf, transmission-line, microwave, microstrip

Do anyone know how to derive the [microstrip stub equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stub_(electronics)#Short_circuited_stub) for all four microstrip below ?

[image: 1]

Comment: Start with these basics http://www.ee.scu.edu/eefac/healy/char.html

Comment: basically you are using stubs as impedance transformers; what is the input impedance of a quarter-wave stub with the far end being grounded?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Impedance of a transmission line v. frequency]

Stolen from: https://www.edn.com/design/test-and-measurement/4424529/So-you-think-you-understand-transmission-lines-

But anyways, that's the impedance of some transmission line that's open on the other end. You can see it decreases in impedance initially, which is the hallmark of a capacitor. Then it sharply decreases and starts going back up, which is a resonance and can be modeled by a inductor in series with the capacitor.

If you look at the impedance of a transmission line:

$$
Z_{in}(l) = Z_0 \frac {Z_L + jZ_0 \tan(\beta l)} {Z_0 + jZ_L \tan(\beta l)}
$$

where \$ \beta = \frac {2 \pi} {\lambda}\$.

Try simplifying and graphing that equation when \$Z_L = 0\$ (shorted stub) and \$Z_L = \infty\$ (open stub).

You'll see the kind of behavior I described--increasing or decreasing impedance wrt frequency, and a resonance at \$l = \frac  \lambda 4\$.

Comment: ok, thanks for your reply. However, I am looking for derivation for each of four cases in my original question. You only explained the first case in your answer.

Comment: Are you having trouble with something particular in the derivation or do you not know where to begin? I think the general community rules dictate I'm supposed to guide you but not do all the work.

Comment: David Pozar's book (Microwave Engineering) does not derive the **analytical expression** for the rest of the cases. He just used smith chart (which is not I want in this question) to do the explanation.

Comment: I assume you get how to derive why open and shorted stubs look like inductors and capacitors when l << lambda?

Comment: Ah, okay I get it now. I am fairly certain the behavior of a stub isn't EXACTLY supposed to match the lumped element version; I believe the lumped element versions just capture the fact that it resonates in a particular way such that the impedance drops to 0 or rises to infinity at a certain frequency.

Comment: I might ask my professor to confirm if this is true.

Comment: If you graph the two you can kind of see how much they "disagree". Since they aren't really equal there's no rigorous way to prove this other than some handwavey "close enough" heuristics unfortuantely